# Test GCP Cloud Function locally with a different file

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, functions-framework

I have a GCP Cloud Function that works just fine.  I invoke it locally like this:

`npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=getData`

This command launches an http trigger as http://localhost:8080.

The command does not have any parameters to specify the file to use.  It uses index.js.

I would like to test with a copy of index.js that I have named test.js.

How can I launch test.js with [Functions Framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/function-frameworks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's highly likely that the framework is using the node module's entrypoint as defined in the [main](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#main) attribute of your package.json.  Typically that is some path to index.js, but you can change it to whatever file you want.

The only [documented options](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs?tab=readme-ov-file#configure-the-functions-framework) to change where the framework looks for file is `--source`, which just changes the source folder (which probably still requires a package.json with a main entrypoint).

One final thing to consider is the deeply embedded [documentation on using TypeScript](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/main/docs/typescript.md), which shows a clear example of setting `main` to different file (emphasis mine):

> Update your package.json with scripts for building and running your
> application:
>
> ```
> {
>   "main": "dist/index.js",
>   "scripts": {
>     "build": "tsc",
>     "start": "functions-framework --target=TypescriptFunction",
>     "prestart": "npm run build",
>     "gcp-build": "npm run build"
>   },
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> - **The main field must be configured to the compiled source code file
>   that contains your function source.**

Comment: excellent!  it is actually "main": "test.js".  tested and works.  txs!